# Error in compiling LaTeX (bmcart.cls not found)

Tags: errors, r

I'm a complete beginner to LaTeX. I want to try a latex template, so I:

1. Created a new R Sweave file in RStudio
2. Copied and pasted the source in https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/biomed-central-article-template/gcgcxphtpccx#.VmAWmIQVfFI

Then I tried to compile it to PDF. I got this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `bmcart.cls' not found.
```

I don't understand the problem and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `bmcart` class is not distributed with TeX Live or MiKTeX, as far as I know. You can download it at http://www.biomedcentral.com/authors/tex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download the `bmcart.cls` file. Or you can create it by the following way.

1. Create an empty text file `bmcart.cls` in the same directory where you have the `tex` file on which you are running `pdflatex`.

2.Then goto [this page.](https://github.com/HongjianLi/tex/blob/master/BMC/bmcart.cls) there you could find the text of the required `bmcart.cls` file.

3. Copy the whole text (it has 1816 lines) and paste into the `bmcart.cls` file you have just created and save it.
4. Then run your `tex` file.

Hope this will help..